# SQL Multiple Left Joins on Same Parent Key

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables that join onto each other:

- TableA(ID, name, amount) (1 row)
- TableB(ID, title) (3 rows)
- TableC(ID, name, title) (3 rows)

The query:

```
Select *
from TableA a Left Join
     TableB b
     on a.ID = b.ID Left Join
     TableC c 
     on a.ID = c.ID and a.name = c.name
```

This produces many duplicates because the second left join is joining onto the result of the first one.

E.g. 1st left join leaves you with 3 rows (1x3), then second the second joins onto this result to get 9 (3x3).

How would I produce a result that would list the ID, Name, Title, Amount in each row distinctly? 
eg:

```
TableA.ID, TableA.Name ,TableB.Title1, TableA.Amount
TableA.ID, TableA.Name ,TableB.Title2, TableA.Amount
TableA.ID, TableA.Name ,TableB.Title3, TableA.Amount
TableA.ID, TableA.Name ,TableC.Title1, TableA.Amount
TableA.ID, TableA.Name ,TableC.Title2, TableA.Amount
TableA.ID, TableA.Name ,TableC.Title3, TableA.Amount
```

I initially tried spiting these tables joins into seperate tables and then unioning them together, this works but I think there must be a simpler way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `union all`:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.title, a.amount
from TableA a Left Join
     TableB b
     on a.ID = b.ID 
union all
Select a.id, a.name, b.title, a.amount
from TableA a Left Join
     TableC c
     on a.ID = c.ID and a.name = c.name
```

Comment: Following that logic, if I had another entry in the main table that joins onto Table B but not onto Table C that would produce 3 rows for each TableB.Title and another row for TableC.Title as null Right?

Comment: @Tolki . . . If you had columns in one table that you want that are not in the other, then you would explicitly populate them with `null` in the query on the *other* table.

Comment: @Tolki . . . Is there a reason you accepted an answer posted four minutes after this one and which is essentially the same?  (Except that this one is correct with respect to where `amount` comes from.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use inner join(left join is not needed) with union all

```
Select a.ID, a.Name ,b.Title, b.Amount
  from TableA a 
  join TableB b on a.ID = b.ID
union all
Select a.ID, a.Name ,c.Title, c.Amount
  from TableA a 
  join TableC c on a.ID = c.ID
```

Comment: If I wanted to include those that are in the main table but are in neither TableB or TableC should I do another union onto a outer left join on both?

Comment: @Tolki yes,if it's the case,then you need to consider outer joins,but due to your sample output that's not needed.